# php mailer does not send degree symbol

Tags: php, urlencode

OK, I have a php mailer program that works great sending html emails with total success UNLESS they contain a degree symbol or ampersand.

I imagine that it's an encoding issue but no-matter what I try the output email stops after (and including) the degree symbol.

Can I have another pair of eyes please. Here is the relevant php code:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charSet=utf-8" . "\n";
$headers .= "bcc: $emailList\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $data1. "<" . "xxx@gmail.com".">\r\n";
// next include a reply to
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $data7 . "\r\n";
// often email servers won't allow emails to be sent to
// domains other than their own.  The return path here will
// often lift that restriction so, for instance, you could send
// email to a hotmail account. (hosting provider settings may vary)
// technically bounced email is supposed to go to the return-path email
$headers .= "Return-path: " . $data7. "\r\n";

// now we can add the content of the message to a body variable

$message = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
$message .= "<html><head><title>Online test - ".$data8."</title></head><body>";
$message .= "<p style='font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;color:blue'>".$data1.", you have attempted ".$data3. " questions";

$message .= " in ".$data4." minutes and ".$data5." seconds";

$message .= " and scored a total of ".$data2.".</p>";
$message .= " <p style='font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;color:blue'>Final percentage = ".$data6."%</p>\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "<p style='font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;color:blue'>The following questions were answered incorrectly: </p><hr /><ul>";

foreach($myWrongArray as $my_Array){
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n<li style='font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;color:teal'>".$my_Array."</li>";  
}
//$message = strip_tags($message);
$message .= "</ul><hr /></body></html>";
// finally, send the email
mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Try using `&deg;` and `&amp;`

Comment: these also get truncated. The ampersand has the same effect as the degree sign. If the string is "the temperature today is 30ºC and the sun is shining" all that arrives is "the temperature today is 30"

Comment: If you echo out the `$message` does it look as expected?

Comment: I don't know how to echo out from a mailer file, but when I sent the array string to a text file it was also truncated, leading me to think that it may not be getting sent correctly to php from ajax. But the array string is complete in javascript when checked with alert(string)

Comment: Try replace this `mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);` with this: `echo $message; die();`

Comment: I tried that, but there is no html document in which to give an echo message. My scheme runs HTML with a call to a javascript file, which in turn send to php using ajax. The php only sends an email after unpacking the array string and formatting it for html email.

Comment: There is some suggestion that the problem lies with the AJAX using get rather than post.

Comment: That sounds like it could definitely be the issue, if the values are being passed as query params (GET) it could definitely cause issues, especially the ampersand.

Comment: OK, I changed the AJAX to post and installed jquery and now the Array is  being passed with the degree symbol. However, I now have a problem with the php leaving me with inverted commas around commas between the Array members and square brackets at the beginning and end of the Array in the final email ...

Comment: OK, the answer was staring me in the face. I had to use json_decode on my string/array on arrival in PHP. Case closed - thanks all.